# Inverse Reinforcement Learning for Markov Games

Tags: reinforcement-learning

This is an Inverse Reinforcement Learning (IRL) problem. I have data (observations) on actions taken by a (real) agent. Given this data I want to estimate the likelihood of the observed actions in a Q-learning agent. Rewards are given by a linear function on a parameter, say alpha.

Thus, I want to estimate the alpha that makes the observed actions more likely to be taken by a Q-agent. I read some papers (i.e. Ng & Russel 2004), but I found them rather generalistic.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! This is an interesting post, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: HI, thanks! My question is how could I implement an IRL algorithm, like [Ng and Russell, 2000], to a Markov game where multi-agents have opposite interests. The game is simple though, as it is a  matrix game. I read some papers on IRL, but neither of them accounts for a multi-agent framework. Actually what I ask is for any ideas on how to approach to a problem of this nature.

Comment: Have you looked into the work done by Deepmind on AlphaStar for StarCraft?
They use a combination of different methods to achieve their goal - one of which is IRL. You can read more about their outline of implementation here: https://deepmind.com/blog/article/alphastar-mastering-real-time-strategy-game-starcraft-ii